# What is the `Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions` in dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

I don't know why the dart compiler shows me an error in my code. What is that actually means? Thanks.

Source:

```
          const SliverAppBar(
        pinned: true,
        expandedHeight: 300.0, // TODO: check out later
        flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
            title: new Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('_SliverAppBar'),
                Text('subtitle'),
              ],
            ),
            background: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Info'),
              ],
            )),
```

[image]

Comment: You have declared you SliverAppBar as a constant

Answer (score 13):

I have commented the original answer that lead to that problem. But here is why:

As @aziza pointed, you have instantiated your `SliverAppBar` with the `const` keyword. Therefore, all properties should be instantiated with `const`.

In your case, just changing from `new Column` to `const Column` would solve the problem, but, dart 2 can infer how it will instantiate the class. Just omit the `new` and `const` keywords, and let dart do the work.