# Flutter: how to apply defaultValue when I create a model with null value when using json_serializable?

Tags: flutter

```
@JsonSerializable()
class TestModelA {
  @JsonKey(defaultValue: 'jp')
  final String? language;
  @JsonKey(defaultValue: 'jp')
  final String? location;

  TestModelA(this.language, this.location);

  factory TestModelA.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$TestModelAFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$TestModelAToJson(this);
}
```

I have this `JsonSerializable()` with the `@JsonKey` defaultValue. How can I assign that default value?

When I create the model with null values, it just sets with the null values. How can I create TestModelA by assigning defaultValues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code. JSON if null then pass the values using constructor

```
factory TestModelA.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      json!=null? _$TestModelAFromJson(json): TestModelA("English","US");
```

Comment: for more read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66043385/how-to-set-a-default-value-for-an-object-in-json-serialisable

Comment: Can I just remove `@JsonKey` and use that instead?

Comment: yes, you can do that.