# Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions? solution

Tags: flutter

[Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGzO8.png)

Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions.I am new to flutter, I couldnt find the answer anywhere. i am stuck please help. Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions. why this error in that line questions[0]. in the image?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit] your question to include the code/error as _text_ rather then an image

Comment: remove const before Expanded wdget

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the \`Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions\` in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49944135/what-is-the-arguments-of-a-constant-creation-must-be-constant-expressions-in-d)

Answer (score 0):

array `questions` is `const`, but `questions[0]` is not `const`.
to get rid of error you should remove `const` word before Expand.

more about const vs final [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50431087/5243472)

Answer (score 0):

When using variables in this way, you should use 'final' instead of 'const' and you should update your question list like this:

```
  final List<String> questions = [
    "Java is a Procedural Language?",
  ];
```